# How to find content in Curly braces

Tags: sed, grep, find

I have a file:

```
   [{ 
    abc
    def
    123
   }]
    
[{
    abc
    456
    789
}]
```

var="789"
i want find (grep sed ...) $var return results Curly braces :

```
        {
                abc
                456
                789
        }
    
or
       [{
            abc
            456
            789
        }]
    
or
            abc
            456
            789
```

i try: `grep '[.*${var}.*]' file` but return results:

```
{ 
        abc
        def
        123
       }
        
    {
        abc
        456
        789
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The post is updated more

Answer (score 0):

If the blocks are separated by empty lines, then you can read the file in "paragraph" mode:

```bsh
awk -v RS="" '/789/' file
```

If, like here, the blocks are separated by "blank" lines (there are tabs or spaces in the separating line), then the record separator is a bit more complicated:

```bsh
awk -v RS='\n([[:blank:]]+\n)+' '/789/' file
```

To pass the pattern as a variable:

```bsh
awk -v RS="" -v patt="$var" '$0 ~ patt' file
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the pattern as a variable:

```
awk -v RS="" -v patt="$var" '$0 ~ patt' file
```

it return results as value orginal:

```
 [{ 
    abc
    def
    123
   }]
    
[{
    abc
    456
    789
}]
```